# Fetch Images on Frontend Side

Tags: magento-1.9, module, frontend

I was Created one Custom Module. In that Module Image uploaded from the Backend Side, now I want to Fetch Image on Frontend Side not image name.
Can Any one help me? Any kind of help will appreciated.

Here is my phtml file :

```
<?php    
     $collection = Mage::getModel('recipe/recipe')->getCollection();


?>

    <?php   echo "<table border=2>
            <tr>
            <th><b>Category Id</th>
            <th><b>Category Name</th>
            <th><b>Category Slug</th>
            <th><b>Category Image</th>
            <th><b>Parent Category</th>
            <th><b>Creation Time</th>
            <th><b>Update Time</th>
            <th><b>Status</th>
            </tr>";


    foreach($collection as $data)
    {
?>  

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data->getId(); ?>
                <td><?php echo $data->getCategoryName();?>
                <td><?php echo $data->getCategorySlug();?>

                <td><?php echo $data->getCategoryImage();?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->getParentCategory();?>
                <td><?php echo $data->getCreatedTime();?>
                <td><?php echo $data->getUpdateTime();?>
                <td><?php echo $data->getStatus();?>

            </tr>

<?php   
    }

?> 
    </table>
```

And also in database my image filed name is `category_image`

Comment: are you saving image in DB?

Comment: @Ashish Madankar : yes I am saving image in DB. but only image name.

Comment: @H_Parekh can you provide code and database detail so anyone can understand better your scenario

Comment: @ Murtuza Zabuawala : I am Edit my question , now you can see code.

Comment: Where are you saving your images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `td` please try below code

```
  <td> <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media/category_image'). $data->getCategoryImage(); ?>">
```

and If your image is in root directory of media then image will appeared

Comment: :my image directory is media/category_image

Comment: @H_Parekh  check updated answer

Comment: @H_Parekh You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can load your module

```
$model = Mage::getModel('vendor/model')->load(the required id);
```

Then You can call the Image Field for Example your Field name is image in DB

```
$model->getImage() // this will give you image name
```

Then In your phtml file you can create img tag to display

```
$imagePath = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'vendorName/';
<img src="<?php $imagePath.$model->getImage() ?>" alt="<?php $model->getTitle() ?>"/>
```

Note: I have given an example so the following image should be in such dir

```
<magento root>/media/vendorName/Image.jpg
```